# How to create an Array from external string file

Tags: c#

How add add array in Speech recognition program see below code ? I tried
 use streamRead read a string and make a array and put  behind `commands.Add(new    String[]`,     see the code below but could not make it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

    //Speech to Text 
       amespace CSharp_Speech_ConsoleApp

        {
        class Program
        {

         [DllImport("winmm.dll")]

         public static extern int waveInGetNumDevs();

         SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new 
         SpeechRecognitionEngine(new      
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));   

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
         // Make a Keywords array
         Choices commands = new Choices(); 
         //How to make this array  by importing strings from a file ? 
         commands.Add(new String[] { "Good morning.","Hello Mike.",
         "Good morning Eddy.","Good afternoon.","Good Evening","Hello",          
         "How are you", "Listen to me Mike", "Stop listening Mike!"
        });

             GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();

             gBuilder.Append(commands);
             Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

             recogEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);


         //get total number of sound input devices

          int waveInDevicesCount = waveInGetNumDevs(); 

          if(waveInDevicesCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No microphone detected.!");    

        }

        else

    {
            Console.WriteLine("Microphone detected. "); 

            recogEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            recogEngine.SpeechRecognized += recogEngine_SpeechRecognized;

            recogEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    }    

        Console.ReadLine();
       }
     // Console Display Speech Recognized result Text 
       static void recogEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender,  
       SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
    {

         string managedString = e.Result.Text;

         char[] st = managedString.ToCharArray();

         Console.WriteLine(st);

       }

      }

    }
```

Comment: show us strcture of data in your file.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` and/or `String.Split` are what you want to use

Answer (score 3):

> How to make an array by importing strings from a file ?

This will give you all the lines from a file:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"PathToYourFile");
```

The above reads all lines from the file into memory. There is another method which will read the lines one by one as you need them:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"PathToYourFile");
```

This one returns `IEnumerable<string>`. For example, lets say your file has 1000 lines, `ReadAllLines` will read all 1000 lines into memory. But `ReadLines` will read them 1 by 1 as you need them. Therefore, if you do this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"PathToYourFile");
var line1 = lines.First();
var lastLine = lines.Last();
```

It will only read the first and the last line into memory even though your file has 1000 lines.

So when to use the `ReadLines` method?

Let's say you need to read a file which has 1000 lines and the only lines you are interested in reading are 900 to 920, then you can do this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"PathToYourFile");
var line900To920 = lines.Skip(899).Take(21);
```

Comment: Choices commands = new Choices();          
         commands.Add(new String[] { (Lines) }

Comment: Sorry? Are you asking me something?

Comment: Can I write code like this, use Lines replace all strings in { } ? :         
 Choices commands = new Choices();          
 commands.Add(new String[] { (Lines) }

Comment: If you use `ReadAllLines` then you can pass that directly into it like this `commands.Add(lines)` because it already is `string[]`.  Assuming `lines` is  the variable like this `var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path")`

Comment: @Yoshi : I tested this way : string[] arr1 = new string[] { "Good morning.","Hello Mike.", "Good morning Eddy.","Good afternoon.","Good Evening","Hello",  "How are you", "Listen to me Mike", "Stop listening Mike!" }; 
Choices commands = new Choices(); 
commands.Add(new String[] { (arr1) } ; // but never work.

Comment: @Jason does this answer your question?