# C# Check if txt contains string and output the line below it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a chat-bot of sorts and
I have a txt file that contains questions and answers in Q,A,Q,A,Q,A format:

Dogs are cats?

No they are not

Cats are dogs?

No they are not

I need to check if the text file contains the input and then set the output value to the answer which is a line below the question. Here is what i have so far.

```
    static string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "memory.txt");

    static IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path);
    static string inputValue;
    static string outputValue = " ";

        while (!shutdown)
        {
            Console.Write("User: ");
            inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
            inputValue = inputValue.ToLower();
            inputValue = inputValue.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '.', ',', ':', ';', '*' });
            StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

            if (inputValue == "hi" || inputValue == "hello" || inputValue == "greetings")
            {
                outputValue = "Hi";
            }
            else if (inputValue.Contains("how are you"))
            {
                outputValue = "Good";
            }
            else
            {

                if (File.ReadAllLines(path).Contains(inputValue))
                {
                    outputValue = //This is what i have to figure out
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }

            Console.Write("Computer: ");
            Console.WriteLine(outputValue);
            outputValue = " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't think this quite constitutes as `artificial-intelligence`

Comment: I am working on a chat-bot of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*, `SkipWhile`:

```
outputValue = File
  .ReadLines(path)
  .SkipWhile(line => line != inputValue)
  .Skip(1)
  .FirstOrDefault();

if (outputValue != null) {
  //TODO: outputValue has been found, put relevant code here  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// load the file in the list
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

// get the position of the question
int question_position = lines.IndexOf(inputValue);

// check if the question was found AND if there is a line below it with the answer
if (question_position >= 0 && lines.Count() > question_position + 1)
{
    // assign the answer to the outputValue
    outputValue = lines[question_position + 1];
}
```

Comment: It couldn't convert string[] to <string>

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `File.ReadAllLines` because that will read the entire file into memory. Read it line by line instead of reading the entire file. It is possible the question may be on the first line so why read the entire file into memory.

```
string outputValue = "";
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines( path );
foreach( var thisLine in  lines) 
{
   if( thisLine.Contains( inputValue ) ) 
   {
      // Get the answer from the next line
      var answer = lines.Take( 1 ).FirstOrDefault();
      if( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( answer ) ) 
      {
         outputValue = answer;
      }
   }
}
```

You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371821/how-to-create-an-array-from-external-string-file/41371905#41371905) for more details on the difference between `ReadAllLines` vs `ReadLines`.

Comment: I was looking more of a if statement but thanks though i tried your suggestion.

Comment: I had difficulties with the foreach statement mainly the in inside.