# Exploding a lambda expression

Tags: c#

The code below works for me however, I would like to add a condition before it is added to the table. What I need is - if the "Scan Time" is between two dates, then it should be added to the "table" if not, then it should be disregarded.

This is for selecting the file..

```
private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Title = "Select the file to open.",
        Filter = "DAT (*.dat)|*.dat|TXT (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*",
        InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    };

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFilePath.Text = ofd.FileName;
        loadDataToGridview();
    }
}
```

This is for reading the file then adding it to the datagridview

```
private void loadDataToGridview()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Emp ID");
    table.Columns.Add("Scan Time");
    table.Columns.Add("Undefined 1");
    table.Columns.Add("Undefined 2");
    table.Columns.Add("Undefined 3");
    table.Columns.Add("Undefined 4");

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text).ToList();
    lines.ForEach(line => table.Rows.Add(line.Split((char)9)));
    return table;
}
```

I got the loadDataToGridview method from here but I do not know how to explode the

```
lines.ForEach(line => table.Rows.Add(line.Split((char)9)));
```

lambda expression to include the condition that I need. Let's assume that the name of the datepickers are dateFrom and dateTo.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just adding a .Where(x => yourconditionhere).ForEach()

Comment: I don't know how to use lambda expressions yet. Can you show me where to put the where condition please. Thanks.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `ReadAllLines` method because it will load the entire file into memory. In other words, why load the entire file if only 1 line is between your dates.

Use the `ReadLines` method instead. Why? See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371821/how-to-create-an-array-from-external-string-file/41371905#41371905).

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("").Select(x => Split(x)).Where(x => IsBetweenDates(x[1]));
lines.ForEach(row => table.Rows.Add(row));
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

You should add your own error handling here as per your needs. I have added a few for you:

```
private bool IsBetweenDates(string value)
{ 
    var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return dateValue >= fromDate.Value && dateValue <= toDate.Value;
}

private string[] Split(string line)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x))
    {
        // There is nothing in this line. Is this allowed in your case?
        // If yes do whatever you need to do here. For example, log it or something.
    }
    var splits = line.Split((char)9);
    if (splits.Length != 6)
    {
        // This line does not have 6 fields so what do you want to do?
    }

    return splits;
}
```

Comment: He'll need to perform the `.Split()` operation first

Comment: Dang, I just put this in a comment as you submitted hehe

Comment: Also, break that split operation into it's own method imo.

Comment: I get an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in "var value = x.Split((char)9)[1];"

Comment: Please see the edit I have made. The fields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are in the same column when I place it in the datagridview..

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much. I just created var lines2 and split that...

Comment: I also edited in case you are interested. And you may want to edit your question so it does not say that it is all in one column so others know.

Comment: @Ibanez1408  I also think you should edit your question to the original form because now none of the answers make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Where()` [as suggested by @CodingYoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435180/712649), but split the line first (so you don't have to do it twice), using a `Select()` statement:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text).Select(line => line.Split(';')).Where(fields => fields[1] >= fromDate && fields[1] <= toDate).ToList();
lines.ForEach(row => table.Rows.Add(row));
```

You may also want to consider using something like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) instead of parsing the file manually

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use [Select Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) which in turns gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Emp ID");
//Add All your columns
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text).ToList();
lines.ForEach(line => table.Rows.Add(line.Split((char)9)));
//Till the data has been already there in your DataTable. 
//Create a new DataTable for Filtered Records.
DataTable FilteredTable = new DataTable();
//The Statement works like a SQL Statement which is equal to
//Select * from TableName Where DateColumn Between two dates. 
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("date >= #" + from_date + "# AND date <= #" + to_date + "#");
//Now add all rows to the new Table.
foreach (DataRow dr in rows) 
{
    FilteredTable.ImportRow(dr);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = FilteredTable;
```

if `from_date` and `to_date` is a DateTime and not a string, you need to use the ToString(your date format) to get the correct sql statement